# Is the set $X$ is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a proper closed subset of $[0,1]$. Which of the  following statements is always true?

A. The set $X$ is countable.

B. There exist $x \in X$ such that $X \setminus \{x\}$ is closed

C. the set $X$ contain an open interval

D. none of the above

My attempts ; I take  $X=\{x \in [0,1]\mid\ \text{where}\ x\ \text{is rational number}\}$
       from according  to my given set  the answer will be opt A.
         as $\mathbb Q$ is rational and closed  ,,,so option A is correct.

```
  Is my answer is correct or not ,,Pliz verified and tell me the solution  i would be more thankful.
```

Comment: You provide an example of a set $X$ and find a statement that is correct for this example. I presume, however, that you are supposed to find out which of theses statements is correct for all proper closed subsets of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your answer is not correct. Your set $X$ is not closed.

Actually A. does not hold always; take $\left[0,\frac12\right]$, for instance.

And B. does not hold alwyas: take the smaa example as above and $x=0$.

Also, C. does not hold always: take $X=\{0\}$ .

Therefore, the correct option is D.

Comment: thanks a lots @ jose Carlos Santos ,

Comment: @lomberlego If my answer was useful, perhaps that you might mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: ok,,, now  i have done @ Jose carlos Santos.......

Comment: @lomberlego No, you have not. Perhaps that you upvoted my answer, but you did not mark it as the accepted answer. Click on the check mark (✓) to the left of your question.

Comment: ok..i marked now @ jose carlos santos

Comment: No you didn't...

Comment: @lomberlego Thank you.